# Null Pointer Exception while setting OnCheckedStateListener on ToggleButton

Tags: android, togglebutton

A null pointer exception is caused while trying to Set OnCheckedStateListener on ToggleButton. What is that exception? I Checked with the development document and did accordingly..

```
public class AccountViewDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

ToggleButton toggleButton;
LinearLayout testLinearLayout;

public AccountViewDetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_view_details_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    testLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.toggleTestLinearLayout);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonTest);


    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                testLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if(!isChecked){
                testLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the XML Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/ivory"
tools:context="com.cube_me.cubeme.Accounts.AccountViewAttachedFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/groupBackground">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/accountViewDetail_groupTV_height"
                    android:text="Inquiries"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/accountViewDetail_groupLeftPadding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/account_groupTextSize"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainText"/>

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggleButtonTest"
                    style="@style/myToggle"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toggleTestLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/account_companyShippingAddressTextView"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/account_TV_viewWidth"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/textViewBackGround"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/account_TV_rightPadding"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Shipping Address"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/account_secondaryTextSize" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_shippingAddressStreetEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_viewHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                        android:hint="Street"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/editText_leftPadding"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainText"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/account_mainTextSize"
                        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_shippingAddressBuildingNoEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_viewHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                        android:hint="Building Number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/editText_leftPadding"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainText"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/account_mainTextSize"
                        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_shippingAddressCityEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_viewHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                        android:hint="City"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/editText_leftPadding"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainText"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/account_mainTextSize"
                        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_shippingAddressStateEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_viewHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                        android:hint="State"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/editText_leftPadding"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainText"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/account_mainTextSize"
                        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_shippingAddressPOBoxEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_viewHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                        android:hint="PO Box"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/editText_leftPadding"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainText"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/account_mainTextSize"
                        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_shippingAddressPinCodeEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_viewHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                        android:hint="Pin Code"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/editText_leftPadding"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainText"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/account_mainTextSize"
                        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_shippingAddressCountryEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_viewHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                        android:hint="Country"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/editText_leftPadding"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainText"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/account_mainTextSize"
                        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

The Exception Caused

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.cube_me.cubeme, PID: 7869
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at com.cube_me.cubeme.Accounts.AccountViewDetailsFragment.onActivityCreated(AccountViewDetailsFragment.java:42)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2083)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1129)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1237)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1079)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                at com.android.internal.o
```

Comment: have you done this? Any problems?

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize you toggle button in OnCreateView method like this:

```
View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                      Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_view_details_fragment, container, false);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonTest);
    return view;
}
```